# Create Sub-folders in SharePoint Site using workflows

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, subfolders, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I am using the SharePoint Designer 2013. I need to create sub-folders when a folder is created in the Site contents library. Is there a way to set this up without programming using the SPD?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want to create sub folders automatically in SharePoint online with SharePoint designer workflow.

Refer to the following article about creating folders and sub folders using SharePoint 2010 platform workflow step by step:

http://365hq.net/creating-folders-and-sub-folders-using-sharepoint-2010-designer-workflow/

Comment: Thanks for sharing @Lisa. I followed the walk through, but it seems like the flow does not move to the next stage from the first one even when I have the transition set to " go to next stage".